# how to check elements form a csv file with selenium web driver in java?

Tags: java, csv, selenium

Hello guys :) I'm testing a web app with selenium web driver in java. I'd like to download a csv file et check that the elements are the good ones. I'd like to know, please, if Selenium could check elements from a csv file and compare them to elements that I expected.

Comment: Sure it can! You have any code we could look at?

Answer (score -1):

This code allows me just to download and save the file. Now I want to compare or check if the elements are good or not :
public class TestsExtraction extends GestionExtraction {

```
@Test
public void testConfiguration_fichier1() throws BadPageException {
    // Connection to the web app as superAdmin
    connexionIHM(User.SUPERADMIN);
    // go and select the csv file for downloading through the web app
    SeleniumTools.selectionneDansMenuGauche(getWebDriver(), "8", "2");
    // click on the button to download the file
    getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='extractionConfiguration_idServeurSelectioner']/option["+ numeroOption +"]")).click();
    // disconnect from the web app
    deconnexionIHM();
}
```